# Relation between solution space and the kernel of a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a linear system $Ax=b$ with $A_{m \times n}$, and some solution $\bar{x}$, satisfying $A\bar{x} = b$, I have read that all the solutions to this system $x^*$ are given by $x^* = \bar{x} + Kv$ where $K$ is the basis of the null space and $v$ is some vector in the null space. What is the intuition of this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x^*$ and $\bar{x}$ are both solutions to $Ax=b$ then $A(x^*-\bar{x})=0$ so $x^*-\bar{x}$ belongs to the null space of $A$. Also, if $\bar{x}$ is a solution to $Ax=b$ and $w$ a vector in the null space then $A(\bar{x}+w)=b$, so $\bar{x}+w$ is a solution to $Ax=b$. Hence we conclude that given a vector $\bar{x}$ which is a solution to $Ax=b$ we know that all the other solutions are in the form $\bar{x}+w$ when $w$ is in the null space.